# symfony api-platform depth

Tags: rest, symfony, api-platform.com

So far we've been struggling with Symfony, Doctrine, and Serializer depth.

I'd like to be able to provide just one-level-depth JSON REST API with Symfony, allowing me to manage my "foreign key" and relation logic directly from the view.

`GET /people/1`

```
{
  id:1,
  name:"theonewhoknocks",
  friends: [3, 12, 25]
}
```

Using FosRESTBundle, we've been strugling at succeeding on that. (we've seen "depth" anotations and "groups" views for models, but none of this fit our need).

The question is simple, before we make a choice for our future API, we have to know:

***is [api-platform](https://api-platform.com/) able to provide a dead simple one level (with apparent foreign keys) REST API ?***

Answer (score 4):

API Platform can handle that using the [Serializer Symfony bundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html) and its annotation set.

To define what will be returned by an operation we use a `normalizationContext` which define group(s) of property to include in result of an api operation. Property to include have then this group name linked to `@Groups` serializer annotation

```
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ApiResource(normalizationContext={"groups"={"read"}}
 */
class Book {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column()
     * @Groups({"read"})
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="books")
     * @Groups({"read"})
     */
    private $author;

    /**
     * Will not be included in result
     */
    private $secret_comment;

}
```

If a relation column is in a Group as `$author` here, properties defined in a group in the child class will be included in the result

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ApiResource(normalizationContext={"groups"={"read"}})
 */
class User {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column()
     * @Groups({"read"})
     */
    private $username;
}
```

In order to avoid cyclic recursion you can specify the max depth of child relation joins with annotation `@MaxDepth(n)` where n is the max depth (1 in your case). This annotation has to be enabled with `enable_max_depth` property in serializer context of the `@ApiResource` annotation

```
/**
 * @ApiPlatform(normalizationContext={"groups"={"read"}, "enable_max_depth"=true})
 */
class Book {
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="books")
     * @Groups({"read"})
     * @MaxDepth(1)
     */
    private $author;
}
```

Please note that API Platform is in this case an agregation of existing bundles and features. Refer to the main bundles for detailed informations (here the Symfony Serializer bundle)

Answer (score 3):

Be aware that the `MaxDepth` on the symfony serializer might not behave as expected, see https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/33466

The annotation basically says "from here on, render max N instances of THE SAME CLASS into the graph"

So given a pseudo structure like

```
Class A:
    @MaxDepth(1)
    Class B:
        Class C:
            Class D:
```

would render the whole thing `A.B.C.D`, while

```
Class A:
    @MaxDepth(1)
    Class B:
        Class B:
            Class B:
```

would only render `A.B.B`

Which is quite different from what e.g. JMS serializer is doing, where `MaxDepth` really means "From here on, max N steps into the relation graph".

Bad thing is that JMS serializer is not supported by api-platform: https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/issues/753

So the answer to your question, atm, is: no. :/

Comment: While not ideal, a workaround is not to use `MaxDepth` and instead use `#[ApiProperty(readableLink: false, writableLink: false)]`.

Answer (score 3):

As @leberknecht indicated, you might not get the results you are looking for using `MaxDepth`.

This script:

```php
#[ApiResource(
    normalizationContext: ['enable_max_depth'=>true],
)]
class User
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 180)]
    private ?string $someProperty = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: UserClass::class)]
    #[SymfonyMaxDepth(1)]
    private ?User $createdBy = null;
}
```

will return:

```json
{
    "id": 123,
    "someProperty": "objectProperty",
    "createdBy": {
        "id": 20,
        "someProperty": "parentProperty",
        "createdBy": "users/5"
    }
}
```

and this script:

```php
#[ApiResource]
class User
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 180)]
    private ?string $someProperty = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: UserClass::class)]
    #[ApiProperty(readableLink: false, writableLink: false)]
    private ?User $createdBy = null;
}
```

will return

```json
{
    "id": 123,
    "someProperty": "objectProperty",
    "createdBy": "users/20"
}
```